# Giving Persistence Database setting on first deploy of JSF application

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, persistence

I have developed a JSF application with JPA using Netbeans and GlassFish. It is working fine within the Netbeans environment. Now I want to deploy it a remote GlassFish server with different database settings. Is there any method I can give the database settings when it is deployed in the server for the first time and save the settings afterwords? 
I have a persistence.xml file, but the database settings are there in glassfish-resources.xml file.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="HOPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>dsHiLap2</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/ho" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPoolHo">
        <description/>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="connectionPoolHo" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/healthofice"/>
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="DatabaseName" value="healthofice"/>
        <property name="User" value="healthoffice"/>
        <property name="Password" value="health"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="dsDec2012" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPoolHo"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_ho_hoPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="ho"/>
        <property name="User" value="ho"/>
        <property name="Password" value="ho"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ho"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="dsHo" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_ho_hoPool"/>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="ds2013Feb" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPoolHo"/>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="drHoBuddhikaDesktop1" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_ho_hoPool"/>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="drHoBuddhikaLaptop1" object-type="user" pool-name="connectionPoolHo"/>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="dsHiLap" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_ho_hoPool"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_ho1_ho1Pool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="ho1"/>
        <property name="User" value="ho1"/>
        <property name="Password" value="ho1"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ho1"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="dsHiLap2" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_ho1_ho1Pool"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use GlassFish deployment plan to configure different connection pool settings for your remote GlassFish server, since glassfish-resources.xml defined application-scoped resources. The application-scoped connection pool is only created during the application deployment. Please see [To Deploy an Application or Module by Using a Deployment Plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilfm.html#gijyb). Basically your supply a remote server version of glassfish-resources.xml (following module-name.gf-dd-name naming convention) in the deploymentplan.jar.

Another option is not to use the application-scoped resource. You can define the connection pool/data source through the GlassFish Admin console.